# jQuery - function for select elements with same class only

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have the following code, which works fine:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').on('change', function(event){ // This binds listeners to the change event on all the select elements
        var sId = this.id; // store off the changed element id
        var vId = this.value; // store off the changed element value 
        var nId = this.name; // store off the changed element name 
        alert(sId + nId + vId); // for testing
        $('select').each( function(){ // this loops across the same set of elements
            if(this.name != nId && this.value == vId) { // If it is not the triggering element and the value is the same, do something
                this.options.selectedIndex = 0; // reset the value to 'rank' 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code works for **all** dropdown menus on a page - what I am trying to do is limit to only those dropdowns with the class `dropdown_1` - is this possible?

Comment: So use a selector that selects the elements you want. https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 2):

You can just change `select` to `dropdown_1` in the code like:-

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown_1').on('change', function (event) { // This binds listeners to the change event on all the select elements
        var sId = this.id; // store off the changed element id
        var vId = this.value; // store off the changed element value 
        var nId = this.name; // store off the changed element name 
        alert(sId + nId + vId); // for testing
        $('.dropdown_1').each(function () { // this loops across the same set of elements
            if (this.name != nId && this.value == vId) { // If it is not the triggering element and the value is the same, do something
                this.options.selectedIndex = 0; // reset the value to 'rank' 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Oddly, I've tried that and it didn't work - will try again.

Comment: @Homer_J Ok, no problem. If you are still facing the issue just create a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). I will look into it.

Comment: Nothing like human error @palash....helps if 'all' the select options I need to be called 'dopdown_1' were actually called dropdown_1...sorted and working - thanks.